# What can the floor of a square root be rewritten as?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

For example: Let $n$ be natural (positive) number. $\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor$

Floor: round down to nearest integer.

What can I rewrite this as? Can I break it down or apart?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you have in mind (the expression looks already rather simplified to my eyes).

Comment: Can I expand it, like how floor(x+1) = floor(x) + floor(1) ?

Comment: Why do you ask? Do you want a fast way to compute it?

Comment: I was thinking something with `log2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ represents the largest integer $m$ such that $m^2 \le n$.  There is no commonly known, specific symbol or notation to describe such a number, other than $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$.  That said, we could define such a number in advance; e.g., "For a positive integer $n$, let $f(n)$ be the largest integer such that $f(n)^2 \le n$."  Then $n = f(n)^2 + r$, for some $r \in \{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots, \max(0,n-1) \}$.  This specifies the decomposition of $n$ into the sum of its largest integer square and a "remainder" term $r$.

Comment: or $\;\;$ "let $\hspace{.04 in}f(n)$ be given by $\: (\hspace{.05 in}f(n))^{\hspace{.02 in}2} \leq n < (\hspace{.05 in}f(n)\hspace{-0.02 in}+\hspace{-0.03 in}1)^{\hspace{.02 in}2} \;$." $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Also, that decomposition doesn't work for $\: n = 0 \;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer  $f(0) = 0$, with $0 = 0^2 + 0$, and $\lfloor \sqrt{0} \rfloor = 0$.  I don't see what fails in the decomposition, and even if it did fail, I did quite clearly specify **"For a positive integer $n$,..."**

Comment: What would fail in the decomposition is that $\:0\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.04 in}1,\hspace{-0.03 in}2\hspace{.02 in},\ldots,n\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}1\:$ would be the empty range for $\: n = 0 \;$. $\;\;\;$ However, your positivity specification does handle that. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: So are you suggesting that the remainder of $0$ when divided by some positive integer $n$ is undefined?  I find your objection pedantic.  I will change the post accordingly.

Comment: ... No, that's not my objection at all. $\;$